# Why loss function is inside tf.GradientTape block and gradients calculation is outside?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am new in `Tensorflow`. In the textbook example I saw the following code designed to train simple linear model using `Tensorflow 2.x` API:

```
m = tf.Variable(0.)
b = tf.Variable(0.)
def predict_y_value(x):
    y = m * x + b
    return y
def squared_error(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred - y_true))
learning_rate = 0.05
steps = 500
for i in range(steps):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = predict_y_value(x_train)
        loss = squared_error(predictions, y_train)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [m, b])
    m.assign_sub(gradients[0] * learning_rate)
    b.assign_sub(gradients[1] * learning_rate)
print ("m: %f, b: %f" % (m.numpy(), b.numpy()))
```

Why it is necessary to include the definition of loss function into the block `with tf.GradientTape() as tape` , but `gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [m, b])` code line is outside `with` block?

I understand that it may be `Python` language specific, but this construction seems unclear to me. What is the role of `Python` context manager here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From tensorflow docs,

> By default GradientTape will automatically watch any trainable variables that are accessed inside the context.

Intuitively, this approach enhances flexibility A LOT. For example, it allows you to write (pseudo)code as follows:

```
inputs, labels = get_training_batch()
inputs_preprocessed = some_tf_ops(inputs)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = model(inputs_preprocessed)
    loss = compute_loss(labels, pred)

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

# For example, let's attach a model that takes the above model's output as input
next_step_inputs, next_step_labels = process(pred)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred = another_model(next_step_inputs)
    another_loss = compute_loss(next_step_labels, pred)

grads = tape.gradient(another_loss, another_model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, another_model.trainable_variables))
```

The above example may look complicated, but it explains extreme situations that require extreme flexibility.

1. We don't want `some_tf_ops` and `process` to play a role in gradient computation, since they are preprocessing steps.
2. We want to compute gradients for multiple models, with some relationship

One practical example would be training GANs, although simpler implementations are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `tape.gradient` outside of `TapeGradient()` resets context and releases resources for the garbage collector.

Note 2 equivalent examples:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  loss = loss_fn()
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  loss += other_loss_fn()
t.gradient(loss, ...)         # Only differentiates other_loss_fn, not loss_fn
```

The following is equivalent to the above

```
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
  loss = loss_fn()
  t.reset()
  loss += other_loss_fn()
t.gradient(loss, ...)         # Only differentiates other_loss_fn, not loss_fn
```

[source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#reset)